# Humidity and Moisture in Submerged Die-Cast Aluminum Enclosures

Tags: humidity, underwater

I have an electronic enclosure (5" x 5" x 4") made of die-cast aluminum alloy (A360). I plan to use it under water (~5 ft) continuously.

I first pressure test it: I monitor the pressure inside, while exposing it to 10 psi air pressure from outside for 2 min. If there is no pressure increase inside (<0.1 psi change), I consider the seals are good.

Then I submerge it in 5 ft water. I have a moisture sensor inside the box. If any water droplet bigger than 1 mm forms inside, the moisture sensor will be triggered and send a signal out.

After about 15 days underwater, the moisture sensor is triggered. I took it out and didn't see any sign of water inside. I didn't even see any water on the sensor. But verified the sensor works fine. So there must have been some moisture on the sensor surface.

So the question is: Where did this water come from? When I sealed it, the humidity inside was about 45% and the water temperature is a constant 75°F. There is no heating element of any kind inside.

Comment: A: *After about 15 days underwater, the moisture sensor is triggered.* B: *I took it out* C: *and didn't see any sign of water inside.* How much time is there between timestamps A, B and C? (Did the moisture have time to evaporize so you couldn't see it anymore?)

Comment: If the water cooled down within those 15 days, the air inside the box may have hit the dew point. Anyway, dew point has nothing to do with EE rather with physics (so, better ask on that stack exchange site).

Comment: To make this question _slightly_ more about electronics, could you at least post the part number of the sensor?

Comment: Repeat the test, except add a small amount of active silica-gel moisture adsorber. The humidity should rapidly fall when sealed, and remain low. A leak would be seen as a rising moisture reading.

Comment: If it's not hermetically sealed, your going to have problems

Comment: most things leak, some just leak slower than others, If you want to keep your electronics dry fill the enclosure with oil or parafin wax.

Comment: As soon as the moisture sensor stays on, I took it out, air blow dry it, then open it.

Comment: The water tank is in a lab and the water temperature keeps constant at 75F all the time as measured/recorded inside the box.

Comment: Customer doesn't even like potting electronics.

Comment: Since I air pressure (10 psi) tested it before using it, it's hermetically sealed by definition. I can't find any standard further defines this term.

Comment: @RYao: Why does the "customer" care if they're not going to see inside for at least 10-20 years?

Comment: By customer, I mean product/technical support people: they want to be able to repair it within its life cycle. They also want to open/replace battery (I haven't figured out how to test when they reassemble in the field yet.)

Comment: You should fill the enclosure with dry nitrogen gas before submerging it. Let the nitrogen flow for a few minutes to "wash out" any humidity. This is done with professional marine electronics.

Comment: The box needs to be opened in the field to replace battery...

Comment: To replace the battery in the field, there should be seperate sealed boxes within the enclosure for the electronics and the battery. So the electronic box stays filled with nitrogen when the battery is changed. Of course the holes for battery connection should be sealed.

Comment: Good suggestion! That could be an option.

Answer (score 3):

Your 2-minute 10 PSI pressure test is laughable in terms of your actual requirements. Let's work the numbers.

---

Your 4" × 5" × 5" box has a volume of about 1640 cc, or 0.00164 m<sup>3</sup>.

Dry air at 25°C has a density of about 1.184 kg/m<sup>3</sup>.

Therefore, you have about 1.94 g of air in your box.

The dew point is about 2.0% mass of water vapor at 25°C.

Therefore, it would only take about 38.8 mg of water to raise the humidity inside the box to the dew point, starting with perfectly dry air.

It took 15 days (21600 minutes) for that to occur, representing an infiltration rate of about 1.8 µg per minute.

---

On the other hand, raising the pressure inside the box by 0.1 PSI, starting from 15 PSI, requires adding 0.667%, or 12.9 mg of air.

Over a test period of 2 minutes, this would require an infiltration rate of no less than 6450 µg per minute, more than 3 orders of magnitude greater than that of the water test.

---

Given the design lifetime of 10 to 20 years, you're going to need to test for an infiltration rate that's a factor of 500× less than what you're getting now. Cut that in half again if you're starting out at 45% RH.

---

Silica gel can absorb about 30% of its mass of water. Adding 100 g of silica gel inside the box would allow your 20-year infiltration rate to be about 1000× higher than it can be without it. In other words, this could mean your current seals are good enough.

You also might consider pressurizing the box with 10 PSI of dry nitrogen before you drop it in the water.

A high-quality [sealing grease](https://www.duniway.com/images/_pg/datasheet-DC-150.pdf) on your mating surfaces and seals would probably help a lot, too.

Comment: Good calculation based on a wrong assumption: box will leak at 0.1 psi/2 min. rate. A box can be assembled with 0/none detectable leak (0.00 psi in 2 min.). But for some reason, humidity inside still increases over time. What could be this reason?

Comment: I didn't assume anything of the sort. What I'm pointing out that your test for "detectable leak" has a threshold that's too high to detect the tiny leak you do have. Your 15-day water test is far more sensitive than your 2-minute air test.

Comment: I understand. Any idea what may cause this slow leak? Thanks!

Comment: No, since you didn't describe your box in any detail regarding the openings it has and their seals. And in any case, this is getting far afield from the topic of EE.

Comment: Die-cast aluminum alloy (A360) box, assuming a solid box without any seals.

Comment: Interesting! How do you get your electronics inside?

Comment: Just to check the possibility. Is it possible to leak in this case?

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely drop in a Silica Gel packet (that you find in new water bottles when you buy them) as mentioned in above comments. That should help with minimizing the humidity inside the enclosure after it has been sealed and keeping it that way for a very long time. The probable cause must be that the circuit heats up and the submerged enclosure is generally cold causing condensation on the circuit parts due to the humidity in air within the enclosure. Once again this is only a speculation but adding a silica gel packet will definitely give you better durability results.

Comment: I can't use or count on silica absorbance because the electronic box needs to work for 10 - 20 years.

Comment: Then you'll have to make sure that there's no humidity when sealed and seal the enclosure in a very controlled environment. You'll also have to seal it in a way that it cannot be undone again. If the size is small and suitable enough of the box, you should coat it with epoxy with whatever thickness of layer you want so there would be no chance of that box leaking.

Comment: The pressure test is the only verification test during assembly. 45% RH is normal in the room and the starting point. So the question is why it increases when it's (hermetically) sealed?

Comment: My bad, should've been clear. You should try to minimise the humidity as that's the only thing that's causing the problem. There maybe a number of environmental factors surrounding it so the better option would be to try control it from your side. The purpose of silica gel is that once you seal the box with room humidity, it'll absorb almost all the humidity contained in the enclosure. After sealing with it, there will be very low humidity to interfere with the sensor even if there are heating elements around.

Comment: I understand, you try to lower the starting point. But considering 10 to 20 years of life, that's really nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Did some testing and found the leaking through seals is in the molecular flow range (less than 10^-7 std cc/sec). This will keep maximum internal humidity around 70% @75F without any absorbents. Our electronic guys are OK with this condition. I still have 10 boxes underwater for ongoing test and will let you know if anything change. I probably will do a temperature cycling test to see if anything will change.